# How can I constrain the height of a Vuetify Expansion Panel such that the panel title doesn't overflow parent?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have an expansion panel that is inside of a div with a set height. Currently, when a panel expands, the open panel pushes all of the other panels to the overflow of the parent div, which makes them invisible, forcing the user to either close the open panel or scroll down to see the other titles.

Here's an [example](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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) from the Vuetify playground.

I am trying to constrain the height of the expansion panels so that when you open a panel the titles of the other panels are pushed to the bottom of the parent div, but are not pushed to the overflow. And then I would like to be able to scroll through the content of the open panel as the content will not all fit in the parent div. This way, the users can scroll through the open content, while still being able to see the titles of the other panels

Example of how I would like the expansion panel to appear

[image: 1]

I tried setting the `max-height` of the `v-expansion-panels` and the `v-expansion-panel` to `100%`, but the panels always grow bigger than the parent container when open. I also tried playing around with setting the position of the `v-panel-title` as fixed so it is fixed to the bottom of the parent div when scrolling, but the entire expansion panel breaks when I try.

Answer (score 1):

If you always have the same numbers of panels you can do like this :

```
.v-expansion-panel-text__wrapper {
    max-height: calc(300px - 64px - (2 * 48px));
}
```

The 48px correspond to inactive panels title height : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panel/#sass-expansion-panel-title-min-height

The 64px correspond to active panel title height : https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-expansion-panel/#sass-expansion-panel-active-title-min-height

(if you're working with sass you can use Vuetify sass variables)

Comment: Add `overflow-y: scroll;` also and it will work as expected in the image.